# Debugging systemd service that deads on startup

Tags: raspberry-pi, systemd, raspbian

I wrote this simple systemd service to start my application on boot:

```
[Unit]
Description=Autostart
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/bin
ExecStart=/home/pi/bin/Server
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I enabled the service and rebooted. On startup MyApp is not running and the status of the service is "dead":

```
● autostart.service - Autostart
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/autostart.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

with no further indication. As far as I know if my application crashes the status should report the exit error code. Furthermore it should restart after 3 seconds.

Manually launching the service, instead, leads to the expected behavior:

```
● autostart.service - Autostart
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/autostart.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-10-20 12:06:39 CEST; 2min 32s ago
 Main PID: 1189 (Server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/autostart.service
           ├─1189 /home/pi/bin/Server
           └─1198 /home/pi/bin/Client

Oct 20 12:06:40 localhost Server[1189]:   some output from my application
```

How would you debug such a behavior?

Comment: Multi-user is before network is available. Can your service handle this condition?

Comment: Ah! Good point, no, I need the network services. I thought it will be restarted until that becomes available. Hence what should I write in After field? "network.target" I think because I don't need to be online.

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

[Unit]

Wants=network.target

After=network.target

To your unit file. Incidentally your service must be exiting normally when it sees no network available which systemd wont restart automatically because its not a failure unless your service exits with an error.

Your service should return with non-zero for systemd to consider it failure. That can be return 1 in main or exit(1) anywhere in C for example.